# Author signing is missing while uploading Tizen Application

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I used Polaris app generator for converting my android application to Tizen TPK. After conversion, while uploading the tpk file in tizen store, i am getting this "Author signing is missing"

Any solution ???

Note : The application was converted using trial version of Polaris

Comment: Please complete the step mentioned in this question's descripion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540128/signature-invalid-when-trying-to-run-my-project-in-samsung-watch then you'll not get author signing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use Trial version of Polaris or full paid? 
You have to use full paid to be able to put apps in the store. There is a warning about this on app download step.

Comment: This is what I am saying - with trial you can't send app to the store. Read carefully what is displayed on the screen. There is warning about this in Polaris.