# How to convert .apk file to .tpk

Tags: android, apk

I went through the net looking for (PAG) Polaris app generator 
could not find any good link to download it

what is the best way to convert a .apk file to .tpk (Tizen application package) format?

any link of a downloadable working software ?

Comment: You might wish to explain what ".tpk format" is.

Comment: Convert Google Android application package to Tizen application package file.

Comment: "Convert Google Android application package to Tizen application package file" -- that is not possible in general.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177262/author-signing-is-missing-while-uploading-tizen-application

this dev used it but i couldn't find where it is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install an android app on Tizen OS device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648292/is-it-possible-to-install-an-android-app-on-tizen-os-device)

Comment: @Robert no answer is there , given link is broken

Comment: PAG was a commercial service - costs: 5000 USD per app. Seems like this was too expensive and the company vanished.